# How to display directive outside current element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to create a directive with a rendering outside of the current element.

My current example is based on a directive inside a table cell.
I would like the rendering create a row next to the current one

```
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <a mydirective></a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

on click it would produce

```
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <a mydirective></a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    CLICKED !
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Is this can be achieved with the link function ?
Can I still use template + controller options ?

Comment: Yes it can be achieve. What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know where to start. I'm used to link function + controller + template, but the rendering happens inside, and only the replace:true, change the way the rendering happens. I'm looking for an example, cause I don't have found one.

Comment: In the `link` function you get the `element` passed as argument. You can use jQuery's function like parent, sibling, appendAfter etc. to modify the DOM starting with your `element`.

Comment: ok but this doesn't let me use template + controller component to handle rendering 'the angular way' right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with like (just for an hint):

### html

```
<div data-ng-controller="MainController">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td><a my-directive>{{item}}</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

### js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
        })
        .directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A', //attribute only
                link: function(scope, element) {
                    element.on('click', function() {
                        var tr = angular.element(this).parent().parent();
                        tr.after('<tr><td>CLICKED !</td></tr>');
                    });
                    element.on('$destroy', function() {
                        element.off('click');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tbh that's a non orthodox way of doing what you want with Angular, I think a better approach is to model it differently, Add an overlay model entity:

```
<table ng-controller="TableController">
      <tr><td ng-click="toggleRowClick();">Click here</td></tr>
      <tr ng-if="rowClicked"><td>Clicked</td></tr>
</table>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.rowClicked = false;
$scope.toggleRowClick = function() {
    $scope.rowClicked = !$scope.rowClicked;
};
```

If you find your self in your angular app thinking how do I make something affect something outside its element, go higher. :)

P.s. that's a general way, off course you can achieve the same with a directive. For example:

```
<tr my-directive="rowClicked"><td>Click here</td></tr>

angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            clickToggle: '=myDirective'
        },
        link: function($scope, $el) {
             $el.on('click', function() {
                 $scope.clickToggle = !$scope.clickToggle;
                 $scope.$apply();
             });
        }
    };
});
```

Off course if the directive is this simple, it's easier to use the previous example.